# Throw new Error with Object in TypeScript Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I throw a new Error with Object containing Error details in typeScript?

I am using jest for testing typescript code and I want to throw new Error as shown below:

```
mock.spyOn(AppUtils,'util_plane').mockImplementation(() => {
        throw new Error("Error Message",{status:403})
})
```

when I do this, the compiler complains saying:

`Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)`

Comment: Because the `Error` constructor takes at most one argument. What gave you any idea to the contrary?

Comment: Hmm saw in the MDN docs of Javascript that it takes `string,options`

Comment: `options` can only have `cause` property

Comment: I see... thanks @Aleksey L.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Error constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Error) doesn't expect `{status: number}` to be passed to it. You can create and use custom error class:

```
class CustomError extends Error {
    status: number;

    constructor(message: string, { status }: { status: number }) {
        super(message);
        this.status = status
    }
}

// ...

throw new CustomError('Error Message', { status: 403 })
```

Or you could assign status property to the error after creation:

```
throw Object.assign(new Error('Error Message'), { status: 403 })
```

Comment: thanks very much, this was so much helpful!

Comment: If anyone comes back to this, Error now supports a second argument object with a 'cause' property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/cause

Comment: @spinningarrow Did someone tell typescript yet because I still have typescript complaining about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the solution of the first code box is awesome and works perfectly!

Comment: @spinningarrow it seems related to ES target according to [this TS issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49535). I've not checked myself though